# Drawer or shelf slides for 1/2 or 3/4" plywood shelves?

Tags: closet, drawers, custom-cabinetry

I have a very deep and narrow space that I want to turn into usable space by creating 3/4" thick plywood shelves that can slide out so that the deep spaces can be accessed.  The space I am talking about is about 11" wide but 36" deep.  In my mind I pictured a piece of 3/4" plywood with low profile drawer slides fastened to the side profile of the plywood.  I figured 3/4" would surely be enough space for narrow drawer slides to attach to.  I am not sure what keywords to be searching for to get a low profile drawer slide that also extends fully to 30 or 36".

Any suggestions?  I am willing to go with less depth if needed but would like to use as much of the space as possible.

Comment: Did you try 36 inch low profile/full extension drawer slides as the search? You'll probably want 34 or 35"

Comment: @Gunner Yes - I am finding very expensive heavy duty slides only.  I do not need them to hold probably more than 100 lbs and the heavy duty ones have extra tall profiles.  I am considering using a 28" slide and just mounting it towards the front half of the "shelf" - however doing so means I have to have some kind of blocking for the shorter shelf bracket to secure to it looks like.

Comment: Do you need the full extension? It's hard to beat the economy and simplicity of wooden slides unless you're opening the drawer multiple times per day or need it to remain open unsupported. Also, I would suggest adding sides to form a tray if you do use slides. Objects falling off the drawer will be irritating in such a deep space.

Comment: Use HD undermount slides (100lbs. is a lot). Tough to screw into the side of 3/4 ply reliably. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q89ZByosGdg

Comment: @MatthewGauthier no probably not required. Just such a deep space it would be nice to use a lot of it.  You're suggesting to just have a piece of wood above and below the plywood so it has a slit to slide in and out of? Any tips on ways to make it slide smoothly and easily?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Those would probably be ideal. Just too pricey. I realize I am in a conundrum with having such a deep space.  Going to have to figure out a more economical option and probably forget about the luxury of full extension soft close drawer slides for this level of depth.

Comment: at 11" wide, it would be challenging to sneak in there and fasten rails to your side walls.  just plan for it.

Comment: 100 lbs @ 36" extension is a lot of leverage. I doubt you'll find anything other than heavy duty that will handle it.  For economy, I like what @MatthewGauthier suggested, with side blocks forming slots for flat shelves to slide into. A few people mentioned sides on the shelves, I think a back is at least as important. To make them slide easier take a look at nylon furniture slides or chair leg tips.

Answer (score 1):

I would use slides that fit under the movable shelf. With such a narrow space already it would be an loss of width using side mount slides.

If you go with the tray idea then side mount slides would be way easier to secure to the tray sides. Under slides will work tray or trayless.